# Get Index of a String Array after Split using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am trying to get the third index of my splitted string. But I cannot get the exact value using LINQ. I am trying to get the third index value which is "CC":

```
string strInput = @"AA BB CC DD EE";
var xRes = strInput.Split(' ').Skip(1).Take(1).Select(c => c).ToArray();
```

The last line was able to get the exact third array. But I wasn't able to convert it to string. If I do this:

```
var xRes = strInput.Split(' ').Skip(2).Take(1).Select(c => c[0].ToString()).ToString();
```

I get this instead:

> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.String,System.String]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to use index, as already suggested, than this way:

```
var xRes = strInput.Split(' ').Skip(2).First()
```

Answer (score 9):

How about

```
string strInput = @"AA BB CC DD EE";
var xRes = strInput.Split(' ')[2];
```

You don't need to use LINQ to do that.

If you insist in using LINQ, you can do it using `ElementAt`.

```
var xRes = strInput.Split(' ').ElementAt(2);
```

Or `Skip` followed by `First`

```
var xRes = strInput.Split(' ').Skip(2).First();
```

Comment: Yes I was able to do it. I am curious if I can do it via LINQ :)

Comment: Or `strInput.Split(' ').Where((item, index) => index == 2).First();` which is definitely *overshoot* in the context, but helpful if you want a condition on both value and index.